# Uploaded moviepy edited file directly to s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, moviepy

My code is to add watermark on video and upload that video directly to s3.
I am able to do add the watermark on video. Upload that video Directly to s3 need to be done.

```
import moviepy.editor as mp
import boto3

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="aws_key_id"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="aws_secret_access_key"
s3_resource = boto3.resource("s3")

BUCKET = "bucket_name"
video = mp.VideoFileClip('path_of_ video_file_stored')
logo = (mp.ImageClip('logo_file_stored')
.set_duration(video.duration))
final = mp.CompositeVideoClip([video,logo])

final.subclip(0).write_videofile('localpath/filename.mp4')
```

Instead of writing to local from final.subclip(0).write_videofile(localpath/filename.mp4)
I need to write file directly on s3 instead of first writing on local and then uploading to s3. May I know how to write to s3 directly with code solution of above.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to work this out Piyush?

Comment: No. Actually we cannot use buffer for this as we need to process so need it on system. So better to download it to temporary folder process it upload and delete from location.